# Practices for processing and storing user contributed images to a website

Tags: image-processing

Like many people I am handling uploaded user images for a website.  Right now we're just saving everything as a static file and letting the browser resize with HTML, I know suboptimal, hence my question.  I want to move to a presumably better process where the image being served up is already the right size.

Clearly I want to store an original, but I'm wondering the right approach for handling other sizes.  Most general photos need to be viewable in 2 thumbnail formats as well as a larger, say less than 800X600px, format.  Some photos might need to be viewable in some other formats, but each photo will "know" what formats it needs at the time it is uploaded.  So my question is **should I store all versions (3 - 4 probably) of the files and allow my static file server to remain truly static, or should I build a request handler that re-sizes the image from the original on demand?  (or some other option)**

I'm leaning towards generating the images at save time and writing backfill scripts if I ever need other sizes.

Comment: Also, I'm trying my best here to make this question as generally applicable as possible so as to "make the internet, and stack overflow, better."  I think that this question, or some form of it, is something that comes up often and should hopefully have some canonical b3st practice answer.  If any of you question-closing-police come by with an itchy trigger finger, please edit the question instead of voting to close.  I know it's a lot to ask since you'll probably end up with less satisfaction that way, but think about it... it's the right thing to do.

Comment: Awesome, a worthwhile answer comes in and, look at that, so does a close vote without said person considering, perhaps, maybe editing the question or putting a comment to let me know why they think this should be closed and how the question could be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options, the one you proposed (using server side to recreate your images with various sizes then store them statically) or you can use server side script to dynamically serve up your images from the original. You can specify your headers to tell the browser to force cache, so your server isn't constantly serving up dynamically scaled down images.

Option 1 Advantage: The right image, every time.

Option 1 Disadvantage: More space, more files

Option 2 Advantage: Save space and can create more sizes on the fly

Option 2 Disadvantage: More processing power and more dependent on the browser (less optimal on bandwidth optimization)

Personally, I would go the static route, you can optimize file size using good compression/crush techniques and you know explicitly your user is receiving the right file.
Take example on how Facebook, Google, Apple, CNN, and Wikipedia store their images. None of them dynamically outputs an image when it needs manipulation for every request.

Comment: Yea, that's pretty much exactly what I was thinking.  How did you determine that those sites don't dynamically generate them?  I considered looking at the url, but then they could just have some re-writing going on and we wouldn't even know what was happening in the background.

Comment: Various blogs told me on Google and Facebook and the developers themselves via twitter over the course of time. I've looked at some of their static content on Apple, CNN, and Wikipedia and all of them appear to be normal images (based on header) and the image header itself. Most were dynamically created but then stored into the CDN.